# LINQ query to sql query generator in visual studio 2010 or 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

Is there any tools like watch in Visual Studio by which I can see the sql query that the LINQ query is generating during debug time using C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console` the `ToString()` for query.

Example:

```
var query = from emp in Employees select emp;    
Console.WriteLine(query.ToString());
```

Comment: Can you please give any example for this... Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you use the [`Log` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx) of the data context, that will write queries out as you execute them. For example:

```
using (var context = new FooDataContext())
{
    context.Log = Console.Out;
    // Execute a query here
}
```

I believe there *is* a way to visualize the SQL in the debugger interactively, but I can't remember it offhand. (It's entirely possible that Zaheer's suggestion of calling `ToString` will do it... or just inspecting the query in the debugger.)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using the `context.log`, there are some other ways you can get the sql query.

1. Use sql profiler, which is a free tool that can monitor all sql queries against a specific database server. by setting up a filter, you could get all the sql query against a specific database from a specific application. but bad thing is that it only show you executed/executing queries.
2. linq to sql profilter, a tool from codesmith, could nicely help to visualize all queries, easy to track and debug, while also give good suggestions on query optimization.

Though for debugging purposes, `context.log` is good enough.